# how to use ternary operator in sx material ui conditions

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I get a variable depending on its value, I want to set 0 or 3, I wrote the conditions, but it doesn't work for me, how can I fix it?

```
<Box sx={{ p: {withPadding ? '3' : '0'} }}>{children}</Box>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have object for the value of p but should be just number, try this:

```
Box sx={{ p: withPadding ? 3 : 0 }}
```